# ReWrite rule not working with two parametrs

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

im quite new to rewrite rules. 
I can manage with one variable and thats it.

I have webpage Where the rewriterule is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.someserver\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/someserver\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ./index.php?comp=$1
RewriteRule ^(\d+)*/$ ./index.php?comp=$1
```

And it all work fine as it should. But now as i want 1 more variable into URL
i cant get it to work.

Right now the $1 is only numbers.

someserver.com/1554886

But i want two variable.

someserver.com/1554886-SOMENAME-WHATEVER-WORD-AND-HOW-MANY

But it wont show.

i tried smth like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./index.php?comp=$1&string=$2 [L]
```

How do i get it to work?
Do i have to make some changes in the php side as well?
everything what comes after the number part of the URL is there only for 
SEO, the number is Unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more rule to handle two parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(someserver\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?comp=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(.+)/?$ index.php?comp=$1&string=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Dont know if im doing anything wrong but not workig.
If i insert URL like someserver.com/12335453-NAME-FROM then i just get error, and the whole page is not showing up.

Comment: How can i use the same thing for a different subfolder. Example: someserver.com/en/12335453-NAME-FORM . As i like to use different languages

Comment: You can copy this .htaccess in any subfolder and it will work. If it doesn't then I suggest you open a new question with more details.